# Aligning 3 nested divs horizontally

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working within wordpress and getting a bit frustrated with something that seems kind of simple. I'm trying to build a set of 3 boxes with nested divs inside each one.

The end product should look like this:

[image]

I can build the boxes alone no problem, but when I try to display them with the nested divs inside, they align vertically instead.

Here's the code I'm using currently:

```
    #bannercontainer { 
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    align: center;
}
#bcdiv1 {   
    position: relative;
    width: 33%; 
}
#bcdiv2 { 
    position: relative;
    width: 34%; 
}
#bcdiv3 { 
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 33%; 
}
#bannerbox {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: dbdbdb;
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px;
}
#bbdivtop {
border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
    float: top;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
#bbdivleft {
border: 2px solid;  
position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:50px;
    height: 80px;
}
#bbdivright {
border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: 80px;
}
#bbdivbottom {
border: 2px solid;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    float: bottom;
}
```

And the html

```
<div id="bannercontainer">

            <div id="bannerbox">
                <div id="bbdivtop">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivleft">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivright">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivbottom">
                test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bannerbox">
                <div id="bbdivtop">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivleft">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivright">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivbottom">
                test
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="bannerbox">
                <div id="bbdivtop">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivleft">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivright">
                test
                </div>
                <div id="bbdivbottom">
                test
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: a screenshot of what is happening right now would help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `float:left` and change `width to percentage` for main `div with id bannerbox`. Try:

```
#bannerbox {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: dbdbdb;
    width: 30%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px;
    float:left;
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mnBkd/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code with the following 2 CSS rules ...

```
#bannerbox {
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: dbdbdb;
    width: 325px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}

#bbdivbottom {
    border: 2px solid;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;  
}
```